# ERROR] s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of 'bindings' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-parsing

I am facing below error while compiling my jaxb file.

```
C:\bea\jdk160_05\bin>xjc cmf.jaxb
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'bindings' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
  line 2 of file:/C:/bea/jdk160_05/bin/cmf.jaxb
```

JaxB File is

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  version="2.1"> 
    <bindings schemaLocation="bi-cmf-flat_V1_0.xsd" >
        <!-- rename the value element -->
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='DeductibleType']">          
            <class name="DeductibleTypeAttribute"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 3):

The format for the XJC call is:

```
xjc -b <bindinfo> <schema>
```

This means your XJC call should be:

```
xjc -b cmf.jaxb bi-cmf-flat_V1_0.xsd
```

**Example**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-enums.html